# findViewById returns null

Tags: android

I have code:

```
public class HelloWorld extends Activity {

private Button buttonOk;
private Button buttonCancel;

private OnClickListener buttonOkListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v){
        EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);

        CharSequence textFromInput = (CharSequence) editText.getText();
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,textFromInput,duration);
        toast.show();
    }
};

private OnClickListener buttonCancelListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v){
        EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);

        CharSequence textFromInput = (CharSequence) editText.getText();
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,textFromInput,duration);
        toast.show();
    }
};

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    // ToDo add your GUI initialization code here

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    buttonOk = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonOk);
    buttonCancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonCancel);

    buttonOk.setOnClickListener(buttonOkListener);
    buttonCancel.setOnClickListener(buttonCancelListener);
}
}
```

and the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Wpisz swoje imię:"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/input"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
    android:layout_below="@id/label"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonOk"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/input"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:text="OK" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonCancel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/buttonOk"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/buttonOk"
    android:text="Anuluj" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Line with buttonCancel.setOnClickListener(buttonCancelListener); throws an Exception because buttonCancel is null. What i am doing wrong?

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Even though everything in the code seems correct, FindViewById returns null with one of the buttons.

Answer (score 14):

there is no problem with your codes, by right everything should work as per normal.

The most common mistake of encountering null via `findViewById()` method is when you forgot to call `setContentView()` or called it for the wrong layout.

I suggest cleaning your project and try again!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same trouble, but after cleaning my project and running it again it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure but you are calling the findviewbyid's in the class initialisation. I think this code is called before the onCreate method so the view's cannot be found. Initializing the listeners in the oncreate method should work.

Answer (score 1):

At times there are few points to be considered!

This can always happen even for experienced developers as well. I would suggest few points below,

- Check that the `findViewById` is added in the appropriate life cycle of the activity or fragment which ever under consideration.

  - Also verify if the layout is inflated correctly and that the valid layout is set in the `setContentView` - which was incorrect in my case.
  - Also as mentioned above there are some cases where cleaning the project could help resolve this issue.